# Creating a generator out of a recursive function

Tags: python, generator

I have created a method in a BinaryTree class to traverse the tree in zigzag manner.

```
def zigzag_traversal(self,l2r_flag=True,node=DEFAULT):
    """
    traverse binary tree in zigzag manner
    ALG:    pass an additional boolean variable. if variable is true call left to right, 
            if variable is false call right to left
    """
    if node == DEFAULT:
        node = self.__root
    if node is None:
        return
    if node is not None:
        print node.getData()
    if l2r_flag == True:
        self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getRight())
        self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getLeft())
    else:
        self.zigzag_traversal(True,node.getLeft())
        self.zigzag_traversal(True,node.getRight())
```

The above code is correct, logically.

Now instead of printing the data out, I am trying to turn this into a generator and yield the node so that some other method can do some other things with it.

I looked at other questions/answers on stack overflow and modified my code to yield instead of print as below.

```
def zigzag_traversal(self,l2r_flag=True,node=DEFAULT):
    """
    traverse binary tree in zigzag manner
    ALG:    pass an additional boolean variable. if variable is true call left to right, 
            if variable is false call right to left
    """
    if node == DEFAULT:
        node = self.__root
    if node is None:
        return
    if node is not None:
        yield node
    if l2r_flag == True:
        for node in self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getRight()):
            yield node
        for node in self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getLeft()):
            yield node
    else:
        for node in self.zigzag_traversal(True,node.getLeft()):
            yield node
        for node in self.zigzag_traversal(True,node.getRight()):
            yield node
```

But the above code does not give the same output as the code that simply prints the node values out, even though I thought they are supposed to be logically the same. So clearly my attempt to turn my method into a generator is incorrect.

My question is how to transform my original code to yield the nodes instead of print them out correctly ?

Comment: How is the output different? Can you provide some sample input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for node in self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getRight()):
```

At a glance, I suspect the problem is here. You're using `node` both as the name of the variable being iterated over, and as an object being used in the call to `traversal`. If you overshadow `node` in the first loop, then it won't have the right value as you enter the second loop.

Try choosing a different name for your iterating variable.

```
for x in self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getRight()):
    yield x
for x in self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getLeft()):
    yield x
```

Alternatively, upgrade to Python 3.X and you can use the `yield from` statement in lieu of creating a new name just to yield it.

```
yield from self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getRight())
yield from self.zigzag_traversal(False,node.getLeft())
```

Comment: ah! i my haste, i overlooked the fact that i was shadowing the variable. thanks!